# A connection between 2 applications

Tags: java, android

I would like to manage a connection between 2 applications, they will run on diffrent phones.
The purpose doesn't really matters let's say that it would be some kind of a chat.

How can I create this connection between the applications? I know how to do it on pc java programs using the socket and the serverSocket classes but I guess it's diffrent in here since the phone might change his ip when he moves between networks.

So how would you do that? how would you create a connection between 2 applications/phones

Comment: A <-> Server, Server <-> B, I don't think you need to maintain a connection, One data transmission, one connection is enough. Moreover, there are many circumstances that Android may destroy your application process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the scenario you described in your comment, using Push Notification i.e [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) might be sufficient.

So, when `program B` wants update from `program A`, it will ask the server to push a notification (via GCM) to `program A`. Note that `program A` will **not** connect to the server every x time to check for updates.

Another *out-of-the-box* solution is to use SMS if the communication is not so frequent and messages are short. Here I mean SMS that will be processed directly by your app (given it has certain attention word) and will not go to the inbox i.e. no SMS notification on the phone

Answer (score 0):

Since the two phones will, as you note, have changing IP addresses, you'll probably need to use an intermediary.

The general design pattern here would be to have a server with a fixed IP or DNS address that relays messages between your two mobile devices. The simplest implementation would be a webserver, to which each phone would connect via HTTP(S) to transmit data or poll for updates.

There are a number of backend-as-a-service platforms that provide this type of functionality pre-built, and would likely suffice for something like a chat system. Check out [Cloudmine](http://cloudmine.me) and [Parse](https://parse.com).

If you need a low-latency or near-realtime connection, you could also consider implementing your own server that uses the Android [C2DM](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) (Cloud to Device Messaging) service.

Comment: Sounds good but there is one thing that I want to emphasize, the chat example was a bad example since in my case phone A will send to phone B information only when phone B tells him to! so let's say that I implement it buy your suggestion then phone B will tell to the server that phone A needs to send something and the server can't connect phone A, so phone A will have to connect to the server every x time to check for updates which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

See Android's Sample Bluetooth Chat App, It will give you an idea for how it can be achieved.